# How to use StringFormat in MultiBinding?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code:

```xml
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
      <Binding Path=".[ServerName]" TargetNullValue=""/>
      <Binding Path=".[InstanceName]" TargetNullValue="" StringFormat="{}\\{0}"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

but the result I get is "ServerNameInstanceName" instead of "ServerName\InstanceName"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringFormat` is ignored if the target of the binding is not typed as `String`. Therefore, the `StringFormat` on the `MultiBinding` will be used, because `TextBlock.Text` is `String` (it wouldn't work if you were binding to `Label.Content`, because `Label.Content` is `Object` -- a common complaint). The inner one, the binding to `.[InstanceName]`, doesn't have a target that's typed as `String`, because `MultiBindings` must accept values of any type. So that `StringFormat` is ignored.

The following works.

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}\{1}">
      <Binding Path=".[ServerName]" TargetNullValue=""/>
      <Binding Path=".[InstanceName]" TargetNullValue="" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

If you did it your way in order to eliminate the backslash in cases where `.[InstanceName]` is null, you've got a problem. I would write a multivalue converter to insert the backslash, or not, and skip `StringFormat`. There's no way to get `StringFormat` to do what you need it to do here. It's just not smart enough.

C#

```
public class ServerInstance : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var server = $"{values[0]}0";
        var instance = $"{values[1]}";

        if (instance == "")
            return server;

        if (server == "")
            return "";

        return $"{server}\\{instance}";
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{local:ServerInstance}">
      <Binding Path=".[ServerName]" />
      <Binding Path=".[InstanceName]" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks. Eliminating backslash on Null cases is the exact reason I did this. I just wanted to avoid converters.

Comment: @EhsanKeshavarzian I agree, it's always best to keep it pure XAML, but I don't think that's an option on this one.